# EffortJointInterface causes gazebo to segfault

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use `<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>` in my  URDF but Gazebo crashes after starting the controllers. I thought i was doing something wrong, so i tried the RRBot demo and had the same issue: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS Distro: Kinetic
- ROS Version: 1.12.14
- Gazebo Version: 7.14 (tried on 7.0 as well, same issue)

Error (with debug and verbose turned on):

```
Thread 37 "gzserver" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fff4effd700 (LWP 12785)]
0x00007fff11c7773d in gazebo_ros_control::DefaultRobotHWSim::readSim(ros::Time, ros::Duration) () from /home/bob/workspace/devel/lib//libdefault_robot_hw_sim.so
(gdb)
```

Is this a bug? I've noticed other people submitting issues on the repo with the same problem.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311690/effortjointinterface-causes-gazebo-to-segfault/) by [robonoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/39240/robonoob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-30**:
It's a long shot, but do you have any outstanding updates to ROS packages? If so, please make sure to update *all* packages.

Also: are you running this in a Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn, based on your suggestion, i removed my workspace, recreated it, reinstalled all the packages/libraries, and it's now working. Must have been a corrupt library or something. All good now. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [robonoob](https://answers.ros.org/users/39240/robonoob/) with karma: 36 on 2018-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0